# Find in Files results files on another solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, find

I copied a solution to another directory and changed all the Namespaces, removed TFS bindings successfuly. I run the application, browsed some pages and it's all ok.

When i was checking the old namespace last one time i see "Find in Files" resulted some files that are in the old solution. Not all of the old solution matched files but some.

I tried to find what would reference that files in new solution but no success.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit of a fan boy, and this is a paid solution, but I use JustCode from Telerik for stuff like this all the time:

http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx

Other options would be something like Resharper:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Check out the trial versions and see if they help find your issue.

You can also run this powershell command to clean up your obj and bin folders

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

Comment: Christopher i'm telling i click find in files i write the word and click. So i expect .net to find the desired files in my solution. But I see some files that are NOT in my solution but another solution.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and/or re-build your solution to get rid of any old pointers.  I also run a powershell command on my dev folder to delete all the bin and object folders (which is what clean and rebuild is supposed to do but doesn't do well all the time).  I updated my answer w/ the powershell command for easier reading.